# $_POST - проверка на заполнение определенной информацией

Tags: php

Например, я хочу, чтобы мой скрипт обрабатывал данные, начинающиеся с http://google.ru/, а если пользователь передавал бы другую информацию, то он бы выводил текст "Ссылка введена не верно".
Как такое сделать? Вчера ночью копался, ничего толкового не нашел, кроме как проверку на заполнение (т.е. если поле заполнено, работает скрипт, если не заполнено, не работает).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[чтите](http://zavu.ru/R9UImjG/)

ваш случай как то так

```
if (!preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) { //если нет совпадения "php" в строке "PHP is the web scripting language of choice."
    echo "A match was not found."; // то выводим что его нет
} else {
    echo "A match was found.";
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы поиск совпадений проводился только в начале отправляемых данных, т.е. если он начинается так: ehttp://google.ru/ или tthttp://google.ru/ и т.д., то выводится информация, что url неправильный.

Comment: ух) а чуток покрутить код никак?:)
>$str="http://google.ru/";
if (!preg_match("/^http:\/\/google.ru\//i", $str)) {
    echo "A match was not found."; 
} else {
    echo "A match was found.";
}

Answer (score 0):

Ну так это стандартная задача на поиск подстроки в строке. Справки в нете хоть пруд пруди.